# scrollIntoView doesn't move to the element

Tags: html, angular, scroll

I'm using the scrollIntoView to move to a element that has a proper index. It doesn't scroll and remain in the same position

```
 scrollToNextQuestion(indexCard, indexQuestion): void {

  const htmlRef = document.getElementById('lazyAccordionTab-' + indexQuestion);
  console.log('htmlRef --> ', htmlRef);
  try {
    htmlRef.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  } catch (err) {
  }
```

}

I pass the index in which I want to scroll. But doesn't work. The structure of html is here

[image]

What can be the problem?

the element where I want to go printed

[image]

**EDITED**

```
const htmlRef = document.getElementById('accordionTab-'+indiceTabScheda).querySelector('[role="tablist"]').querySelector('#lazyAccordionTab-'+indiceDomanda).lastElementChild;
```

I replaced this piece of code

Comment: Did u inject Document from common library . What is your  document.getElementById('lazyAccordionTab-' + indexQuestion) in console ?

Comment: yes document it's form a common library. the elementById it's exactly the element where I want to scroll. As you can see by edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like that?

```
var topOfElement = document.querySelector('#lazyAccordionTab-'+ indexQuestion).getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.scroll({ top: topOfElement, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: I tried, so it scrolls to top of the window and not to the element

Comment: the offsetTop is zero

Comment: Can u try with querySelector too? I edited answer. And I wonder if it is hidden element until u click. If yes then it will be always 0

Comment: yes it's always zero.. I printed the dom above and the structure is what I showed. I don't know why it doesn't scroll

Comment: so now seems that it moves but it stops before.. doesn't go all the way! is a options problem by "scrollIntoView"?

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example of demo ?

Comment: can u write getBoundingClientRect().top; rather than offsetTop and try again

Comment: so I edited the question.. as you can see now I get the element in this way, and use scrollIntoView. Do you suggest to use the window.scroll?

Comment: yess, it works perfectly.. I don't know how to thank you!! You're the best